# Comportamiento inesperado: variable cambía de valor sin setearla: ¿Tiene explicación?

Tags: cmd, batch

Estaba haciendo este pequeño escript y ocurre lo siguiente lo cual que no le veo explicación.

Código:

```
@echo off
set CurrDir=%cd%
set BatchFileDir=%~dp0
goto :main


:process
set PTH=%CurrDir%\%folder_name%
set PTHEXT=%folder_name:~0,-2%\out    
echo %PTH%
echo %PTHEXT%    
goto :eof


:main
FOR /D %%G in (./*) DO (set folder_name=%%G & echo %%G & call :process)
goto :eof
```

Dentro del for;

```
%folder_name% = %%G = nombre de la carpeta
```

Dentro de la función :proces;

```
En %PTH% la variable %folder_name% = **nombre** de la carpeta

En %PTHEXT% la variable %folder_name% = **path** de la carpeta
```

Salida del programa:

```
Nombre1
C:\Dir\Nombre1
C:\Dir\Nombre1\out
Nombre2
C:\Dir\Nombre2
C:\Dir\Nombre2\out
Nombre3
C:\Dir\Nombre3
C:\Dir\Nombre3\out
```

¿Cómo es posible que la variable %folder_name% cambie de valor de una línea a otra sin hacerle nada?

Pasa de ser esto:

```
%folder_name% = Nombre1
```

A ser esto otro:

```
%folder_name% = C:\Dir\Nombre1
```

Un comportamiento totalmente inesperado. ¿A caso estoy haciendo algo mal?

---

### ------------------El código anterior fue desechado---------------------------

Lo siguiente es el código que hice para sustituir al anterior... ya no se parece en nada al original pero lo pongo por si alguien está interesado en usar alguna parte de él.

```
@echo off
set CurrDir=%cd%
set BatchFileDir=%~dp0
set "FFMPG=%BatchFileDir%ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" 
set "IMGAUX=%BatchFileDir%img2.jpg"
goto :main



:GetWav
for /R "%CurrDir%" %%i in (*.wav) do (
    Echo Procesando el archivo: 
    echo "%%i" 
    set fname=%%~ni 
    set full_pth=%%i
    set "DirTrabajo=%%~dpi"
    ) & call :recodeFiles
goto :eof


:MakeDir
if not exist "%~1" mkdir "%~1"
goto :eof

:recodeFiles
set "fname=%fname:~0,-1%"
set "DIRSAVETO=%DirTrabajo%out"
set "WAV=%full_pth%"
set "MP4=%DirTrabajo%out\%fname%.mp4"
set "IMG=%WAV:~0,-4%img1.jpg"


echo FFMPG:      %FFMPG%
echo CURDIR:     %CurrDir%
echo DIRTRABAJO: %DirTrabajo%
echo MP4 OUT     %MP4%
echo DISTO SAVE: %DIRSAVETO%
echo IMGAUX:     %IMGAUX%
echo WAV:        %WAV%
echo PATH IMG:   %IMG%

call :MakeDir "%DIRSAVETO%"

if not exist "%IMG%" set "IMG=%IMGAUX%"
echo PATH IMG:   %IMG%


if not exist "%MP4%" (

set AUDIOOPTIONS=-c:a aac -b:a 320k 
set VIDEOOPTIONS=-c:v libx264 -b:v 900K

"%FFMPG%" -loop 1 -i "%IMG%" -i "%WAV%" -map 1:a  %VIDEOOPTIONS%  %AUDIOOPTIONS% -shortest "%MP4%"


)

goto :eof

:main
call :GetWav
goto :eof
```

Comment: Lo he probado en mi máquina y la salida que tengo no es la misma que la que muestras. He creado dos carpetas 'a' y 'b' y al ejecutar sale `a``D:\Temp\soe\171296\a``\out` y `b``D:\Temp\soe\171296\b``\out`. El out no lo llega a montar bien. Quizás la versión de código que has puesto aquí no sea la misma que ejecutas tú?

Comment: Al final lo terminé haciendo de otra forma porque no me fiaba de este código... y no encuentro el código original.... pero básicamente era esto lo que pasaba... lo que si puedo hacer es enseñarte el código que hice para sustituir a este por si estás interesado en usar alguna parte de él o algo así... te lo pongo por ahi arriba... Gracias por molestarte en hacer la camprobación.